# jQuery - get index of element, restricted to class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following html:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x y">
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x y">
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which elements get the `y` class - is a dynamic thing, which changes during runtime based on different user interactions.

On mouse over an anchor (I can assume that the anchor is in a div with the `y` class, because only those are visible), I need to get the index of it's container (that div with the `y` class), but restricted to that `y` class.

Meaning:

1. mouseover on "Link 4" should tell me: `0` (first element with class `y`)
2. mouseover on "Link 6" should tell me: `1` (second element with class `y`)

`.index()` doesn't help me here

**EDIT:**
@Kevin B
I've read the docs, but couldn't make it work. The closest thing I could find there was to pass a collection to `.index()`, which I've tried. But didn't work (also, their example for the collection is with vanilla js document.getElementById - that didn't work for me, need to work with classes; tried to adapt: myCollection = $(this).closest('.my-container').children('.y') and passed that to `.index()`, and it didn't work).
I wouldn't post without google-ing first and also going through the docs, don't know why the down vote (not pointing any fingers, I'm not assuming I know who's is it). Just because I said ".index()" doesn't help me"? Well, I've tried whatever I understood I could do with it, and couldn't make it happen. That's why I posted.

Comment: *".index() doesn't help me here"* Are you sure? [have you read the documentation for said method?](http://api.jquery.com/index/) sure seems like it would do the job.

Comment: `index()` is exactly what you need: `$(this).index('.y a')` where `this` is the `a` element which caused the mouseenter event

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) : *"I need to get the index"* .. do you?  You probably don't need the *index* unless this is some derived, non-real-world scenario / technical exercise.   Give each container a 'data-idx=' with the actual value it needs and use `$(this).closest("div.y").data("idx")`

Comment: I've read the docs, but couldn't make it work. The closest thing I could find there was to pass a collection to `.index()`, which I've tried. But didn't work (also, their example for the collection is with vanilla js document.getElementById - that didn't work for me; tried to adapt, and couldn't make it work).
I wouldn't post without going through the docs and searching first, don't know why the down vote. Just because I said ".index()" doesn't help me"?

Comment: @freedomn-m - this is not theory, why would I loose time with that? :)
I have a horizontal list, and on mouse over on elements having `y` class I need to apply an effect, effect which is different if it's the first `y` class element or if it's the last. So 3 effects: first, last and any in-between. The only thing I "added" here was implying that my `y` class elements aren't necessarily one after the other, but in the real scenario they're always consecutive. Made it simple here so I won't pollute with too much html. And I do have more semantic classes than `x` and `y` and `my-container`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, index is exactly what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //mousein
  $("a").hover(function(){
     var parent = $('.my-container').eq(2); // the 3rd "my-container"
     console.log(parent.find('.y a').index(this)); //-1 if elm doesnt exist
  },
  //mouseout
  function(){

  })
});
```

Comment: This works! Given that I select my parent differently, not with `.eq(n)` - but that was just an example, of course. And I actually already know, of course, in what "parent" I am.
`parent.find('.y a')index(this)` is certainly what does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, index is exactly what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //mousein
  $("a").hover(function(){
     console.log($(this).index('.y a')); //-1 if elm doesnt exist
  },
  //mouseout
  function(){

  })
});
```

Comment: I don't know who's the professional down-voter here...
And why? I've just tested your answer and it works.
Does anybody have an explanation as to why this would be a bad approach? Is there a better one?

Comment: Although... I have multiple `<div class="my-container"></div>` on my page.
It only works for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 1;
$(".my-container div").on('mouseover',function(){
  if ($(this).attr("class").indexOf('y') > -1){
      alert(count + "th mouseover on y class");
      count++;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x y">
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x y">
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    </div>
</div>
```